# laravel 7 free hosting in heroku handleError()

Tags: api, heroku, laravel-7

i have a problem hosting in Heroku
the Laravel 7 project is working fine locally, it's based on Andre madarange moviesApp application
the project doesn't need a database so I didn't set up one but I dote that is the problem all the contents are TMDB API based
the app is working 100% locally but when hosted this came up[image: the Heroku hosted website]

here is the repo of my code [GitHub repo](https://github.com/youcef-dz35/movieapp)

Comment: The JSON has no value called "results". You need to output the value of `$popularMovies`'s JSON and see what's in there, because it's not what you expect it to be. Perhaps their API is down; perhaps they block Heroku; perhaps you misconfigured your config and don't have an API token properly sent. Various possibilities.

Comment: It was working fine in local development but when deploying to Heroku this happened !

Comment: Yes. Now you need to figure out why. You will need to do that by logging or outputting (using something like `dd()`) the value of your `Http::withToken()->get()` call to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I still don't get it
when I replaced `config('services.tmdb.token')` with the real token it worked perfectly
thank you for trying to help me guys